# add background color to highcharts stacked Bar Chart

Tags: highcharts, colors, background, bar-chart, stacked-chart

How i can add background color to highcharts stacked Bar Chart column like in picture

[image]

I have try find in highcharts official [documentation](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts) but unfortunately cant find.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straight way from the API to create such a shadow background for a stacked bar chart, but you can create it as a dummy series with disabled `enableMouseTracking` and `showInLegend` options.

**Sample code:**

```
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      stacking: 'percent'
    }
  },
  series: [{
      color: '#ddd',
      enableMouseTracking: false,
      showInLegend: false,
      data: [7, 7]
    }, {
      data: [1, 1]
    },
    {
      data: [2, 2]
    }
  ]
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/7vx2sn8d/

**API References:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.showInLegend
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.bar.enableMouseTracking